# Where is town of Pogena, Russia (or Lithuania) where ancestor born in 1885?

Tags: 19th-century, russia, historical-gazetteer, birthplace, lithuania

On my grandfather's naturalization papers, birthplace is listed as Pogena, Russia. It may be located in Lithuania.

His name is Julius Albert Knoll.

I am also looking for my grandmother's birthplace. Her name is Emily Haak Knoll.

One naturalization paper for her husband lists Poland, Russia as her birthplace.

Comment: One place you could check is the Russian enclave of Kaliningrad which is between Poland and Lithuania.  I don't see a Pogena there but given the movement of the borders over the last hundred or so years it could be a place to start looking.

Comment: Welcome to G&FH SE!  As a new user be sure to take the [Tour] to learn about our focussed Q&A format which is quite different from bulletin boards, discussion forums and other Q&A sites you may be used to.  Please try to ask a single focussed question rather than a question about each of your two grandparents.  You can always ask about Emily's birthplace separately.

Comment: I was able to locate Pogena by going back and finding old maps and finding name changes.

Comment: @Michele Knoll it is very interesting where did you find this town...

Comment: Yes, it's very interesting to know where you found Pogena.

I live in Kaliningrad, and know a couple of local history communities, maybe they will be able to help with your research.

Answer (score 1):

A good place to start when looking for people from Russia and adjacent countries is Jewish Gen. This link will take you directly to pages on Lithuania.

http://www.jewishgen.org/databases/#Lithuania

Comment: Hi Mike, welcome! What did you find for Pogena on that site? You can add details to your answer to make it more useful using the [edit] button right below your post.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to find Knoll surname in [Estonian parish records](http://www.ra.ee/dgs/addon/nimreg/result.php?s_name=Knoll&c_id=0&p_id=0&s_fr=&s_to=&e_fr=&e_to=). As you know Lithuania is not far away from Estonia, so mentioned Knoll's can be relatives. The chances are great because it is not common surname
Also Estonia was the part of Russian Empire for a long time and the moment you mentioned and sometimes Estonian citys' and towns' names are very curios (for example, they can contain specific letters like **õ** which can't be transcribed to English well)

Comment: Knoll is a fairly common German surname so the chance those are his relatives are actually very low.

Comment: @Bregalad, I can't argue with you :-) Maybe (and I am sure) that you are right regarding Germany...